# How can I add CSS to a PHP script?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

This is the script on which I'd like to add some CSS :

```
// Download URLs
        if ( $show_download_links && $_product->exists() && $_product->is_downloadable() ) {
            $download_files = $order->get_item_downloads( $item );
            $i              = 0;
            foreach ( $download_files as $download_id => $file ) {
                $i++;
                if ( count( $download_files ) > 1 ) {
                    $prefix = sprintf( __( 'Download %d', 'woocommerce' ), $i );
                } elseif ( $i == 1 ) {
                    $prefix = __( 'Download', 'woocommerce' );
                }
                echo "\n" . $prefix . '(' . esc_html( $file['name'] ) . '): ' . esc_url( $file['download_url'] );
            }
        }
        // allow other plugins to add additional product information here
        do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', $item_id, $item, $order );
    }
```

It is part of a Woocommerce email (completed order). I'd like to add some CSS there, how can I do this ?

Comment: add it on your style.css located in your theme...

Answer (score 2):

According to Woocommerce documentation, a more powerful (and advanced) way to customize order emails is to override an email template file. WooCommerce uses a convenient templating system that allows you to customize parts of your site (or emails) by copying the relevant template file into your theme, and modifying the code there. Each of the email types has a template file for its content

Can you check woocommerce documentation [here](https://www.sellwithwp.com/customizing-woocommerce-order-emails/)

Comment: Thank you! That script comes from a template that I've copied into my theme. However, I'm unable to move the "download link" in the email template.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code

First Solution

```
<?php
  $css = file_get_contents('CSS/main.css');
  echo $css;
?>
```

Second Solution

```
<style>
  <?php include 'CSS/styles.css'; ?>
</style>
```

Third Solution

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.
Just do like this:

```
<?php if($page=='page'): ?> 
  <style>.container{width:100%}</style>
<?php else: ?>
    ...
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add something on the download do it like this:

```
$prefix = sprintf( __( '<strong>Download</strong> <span style="padding-top:10px;>"%d</span>', 'woocommerce' ), $i );
```

Otherwise, as the others said here, `file_get_contents(foo.css)` or `<? echo "<style>{something;}</style>";`